# Automate SCP copy files from multiple directories (in brackets) to appropraite directories

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I have a bash script used for copy some files from different directories in remote host. All of them have the same parent. So i put them into list:

```
LIST=\{ADIR, BDIR, CDIR\}
```

and i use the scp command

```
sshpass -p $2 scp -o LogLevel=debug -r $1@192.168.121.1$/PATH/$LIST/*.txt /home/test/test
```

that command makes me able to copy all of .txt files from ADIR, BDIR, CDIR to my test directory. Is there any option which can put all of .txt files in appropriate directory like /home/test/test/ADIR or /home/test/test/BDIR ... ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you: do you want to *create* the directories containing the matching text files in your target directory? ("locate" means "find" - more or less).

Comment: I mean 'put' in appropriate directory. Simple example: file a.txt which is in ADIR directory (remote host) will be copied to test/ADIR and b.txt from BDIR(remote host) will be copied to test/BDIR

Comment: Brace expansion isn't performed on the result of variable expansion. Brace expansion also doesn't accept spaces after the commas. You can't use `$LIST` like this. (Unless `scp` is doing something here itself.) Ignoring all of that though I don't believe `scp` can do what you want. `rsync` can though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)?

You could try something along these lines:

```
# Rsync Options
# -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
# -D                          same as --devices --specials
# -g, --group                 preserve group
# -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
# -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
# -O, --omit-dir-times        omit directories from --times
# -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
# -r, --recursive             recurse into directories
# -t, --times                 preserve modification times
# -u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
# -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
# -z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer


for DIR in 'ADIR' 'BDIR' 'CDIR'
do
        rsync -zavu --rsh="ssh -l {username}" 192.168.121.1:/$PATH/$DIR /home/test/test/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally my working code:

```
SOURCE='/usr/.../'
DEST='/home/test/test'
DIRS_EXCLUDED='test/ADIR test/BDIR'
EXTENSIONS_EXCLUDED='*.NTX *.EXE'

EXCLUDED_STRING=''

for DIR in $DIRS_EXCLUDED
do
    EXCLUDED_STRING=$EXCLUDED_STRING'--exclude '"$DIR"' '
done

for EXTENSION in $EXTENSIONS_EXCLUDED
do
    EXCLUDED_STRING=$EXCLUDED_STRING'--exclude '"$EXTENSION"' '
done

rsync -zavu $EXCLUDED_STRING --rsh="sshpass -p $2 ssh -l $1" 192.168.xxx.xxx:$SOURCE $DEST
```